# How to renew a Safari Developer Certificate in windows

Tags: windows, safari, certificate

My safari developer certificate from apple expired, and the documentation relating to certificates for windows developers on the apple website have been removed.

I tried opening the windows certificate manager ( certmgr.msc )
then clicked on the certificate, selected "All Tasks", then "Renew certificate with same key"
but i get the following error message:  "The wizard cannot be started because it failed to contact the active directory."

Does anyone know 5he method for renewing an Apple Safari Developer certificate on Windows XP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK heres the process for Windows XP / Windows 7, if you need to renew your Safari Developers Certificate.

**1**) Create a text file named **certreq.txt**
with the following contents

```
[NewRequest]
Subject="cn=Safari Developer,o=User"
RequestType=pkcs10
KeyLength=2048
Exportable=TRUE
```

**2**) Open a command prompt, change to the directory where **certreq.txt** is and type the following command

```
certreq -new certreq.txt cert.pem
```

**3**) Now login to the Safari Developers Member Center
and then go to the request a certificate page, its currently at:

```
https://developer.apple.com/account/safari/certificate/certificateRequest.action
```

**4**) Click the **Continue** Button

**5**) Click the **Choose File** button, locate the **cert.pem** file you generated earlier and upload it

**6**) They should then present you with a certificate file to download, which you just need to double click, then choose to install it in the previous location.

**7**) You may need to copy the new certificate into the correct locations (i think its just the Personal section you need to copy it to) in the certificate manager, which you can run by typing **certmgr.msc** at a command prompt, to find the correct locations to copy it, find the locations of the old safari developers certificate/s. You may also need to delete the old expired certificates.

**8**) Thats it, you should be able to develop Safari extensions again.